# read id3 tags from mp3 using javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

I know this has been asked here before but my conditions are a little different. I am making a chrome app so i have access to all the latest JavaScript file apis it supports without worrying about compatibility. More over i would really like to do this my self.. ie without any library. A tutorial or a guide will do. After all how difficult can it really be?

Basically i have mp3's that user adds and i want to be able to read most basic information like artist and Album (actually, just these two but others wont do any harm).

I believe i have the idea of what id3 tag is and how can the info be read. I just have to see it in action just once.
Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no need to use binaryajax.js or id3 parser lib anymore. In Chrome at, you can use `FileReader` and `DataView` to read and extract the ID3v1 info. It's just a few lines:

http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/8343485440/reading-mp3-id3-tags-in-javascript

Comment: yea.. i ended up with that only.. you can see the comments on the other answer :D there was no answer mentioning the api so i selected that answer.. but now there is :) thanks anyways for answering :D

Comment: although it works for one song but if i try to add multiple songs (use api in loop), it reads info on of a select few. Others come blank. there is no pattern that i could come up with. i have tried to eliminate *every* other unnecessary variable. i really want it to work.. if you can help, it would be really great..

Comment: This does not seem to work with the Chrome v20 any ideas on why and how to get aorund it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20212560/2450730 i'm trying to find out how to do this with id3 v2.4 using native DataView

Comment: so what about mp3 streams (shout-/icecast)? wouldn't it be nicer if the audio element could provide the metadata? especially when it's already buffering the stream. doing playback and reading the stream for metadata separately seems kind of stupid in the age of metered connections..

Comment: you still need to include the `https://jdataview.github.io/dist/jdataview.js` when using chrome to get the `jDataView` working

Answer (score 8):

This library has good docs. I love GitHub

https://github.com/leetreveil/node-musicmetadata

---

### API

```
var fs = require('fs');
var mm = require('musicmetadata');

//create a new parser from a node ReadStream
var parser = new mm(fs.createReadStream('sample.mp3'));

//listen for the metadata event
parser.on('metadata', function (result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

This will output the standard music metadata:

```
{ artist : ['Spor'],
  album : 'Nightlife, Vol 5.',
  albumartist : [ 'Andy C', 'Spor' ],
  title : 'Stronger',
  year : '2010',
  track : { no : 1, of : 44 },
  disk : { no : 1, of : 2 },
  picture : [ { format : 'jpg', data : <Buffer> } ]
}
```

Comment: How do you initialize the parser in the browser when you don't have `createReadStream` available?

Answer (score 3):

As @joekarl has pointed out, there are libraries to do this for you.  I saw your request for info so you can do it yourself, but here's a gem from the 500+ or so lines from the library on [nihilogic.dk](http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/08/reading-id3-tags-with-javascript.html):

```
var iLong = bBigEndian ? 
            (((((iByte1 << 8) + iByte2) << 8) + iByte3) << 8) + iByte4
            : (((((iByte4 << 8) + iByte3) << 8) + iByte2) << 8) + iByte1;
        if (iLong < 0) iLong += 4294967296;
        return iLong;
```

Not to mention a significant amount of pure Javascript AJAX work.

There's no reason to reinvent this wheel.  However, if you want to look at the code and rewrite it for whatever reason, here are the two libraries files:

[binary ajax library](http://nihilogic.dk/labs/binaryajax/binaryajax.js)
[id3 parser](http://nihilogic.dk/labs/id3/id3.js)

If you really want to cut out any of the AJAX and just start with reading a file you already have (somehow, without AJAX), the second link has a function called, coincidentally, `readTagsFromData`.  I suggest you start there for your goals.

Comment: yeah, my (packaged) app does not use any ajax at all (infact it is completely offline) it uses the filesystem api. i will look into your links to see for the relevant code. thanks a ton :)

Comment: @rockerest in the file which has readTagsFromData, the function requires a binary data as input variable, i have the file as a file input or a blob url. How can i do the conversion?

Comment: I honestly have no idea.  The best bet might be a base64-encoded string representation of the image, but I really have no clue of how to get to that point.  If you have a backend like PHP you could probably read either the file input OR the blob and convert it to a single binary format that you could then feed to the front end javascript.  There's a lot of magic, in there, however, that I can't shed a lot of information on.

Comment: FYI, the first link (binary Ajax) has a function (the first in the file, actually) that returns binary data.  You should probably have a good long look at that to see if you can use it for what you need.

Comment: hmm thanks for that.. i am also using the filesystem api and it has a readAsBinaryString function. i am looking into that right now.. 

[link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-file-readingbyname)

Comment: OMFG! it did the trick! hell yes..! readAsBinaryString was what i needed to read my file as a binary. thanks a ton!