# Read id3 v2.4 tags with native Chrome Javascript/FileReader/DataView

Tags: javascript, filereader, dataview, id3

Based on the answer of [ebidel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6907866/2450730), one can read id3v1 tags by using [jDataView](https://github.com/jDataView/jDataView):

```
document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').onchange = function (e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var dv = new jDataView(this.result);

        // "TAG" starts at byte -128 from EOF.
        // See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3
        if (dv.getString(3, dv.byteLength - 128) == 'TAG') {
            var title = dv.getString(30, dv.tell());
            var artist = dv.getString(30, dv.tell());
            var album = dv.getString(30, dv.tell());
            var year = dv.getString(4, dv.tell());
        } else {
            // no ID3v1 data found.
        }
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]);
};
```

Chrome and other browsers have now implemented DataView (I'm interested only in Chrome).  I'm curious if someone knows how to:

1. Read tags using the native DataView
2. Reading id3 v2.4 tags (including APIC image 'coverart')

The point is that I have no experience with binary files, and totally don't know how to jump to the correct tag position, or what little endian and long endian (or whatever) are. I just need an example for one tag - let's say the title, the `TIT2` tag, which I hope helps me to understand how to jump to the correct position and to read the other tags also:

```
function readID3() {
    //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataView
    //and the position
    //http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames
    //var id3={};
    //id3.TIT2=new DataView(this.result,?offset?,?length?)

    /*
     ?
     var a=new DataView(this.result);
     console.dir(String.fromCharCode(a.getUint8(0)));
     ?
    */
}
function readFile() {
    var a = new FileReader();
    a.onload = readID3;
    a.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]);
}
fileBox.addEventListener('change', readFile, false);
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s492L/).

---

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/s492L/3/

I added `getString` so I can read the first line and check if it contains ID3.
Now I need to find the position of the first tag (TIT2) and the 'variable' length of that string & also check if it's version 2.4.

```
//Header
//ID3v2/file identifier    "ID3"
//ID3v2 version            $04 00
//ID3v2 flags         (%ab000000 in v2.2, %abc00000 in v2.3, %abcd0000 in v2.4.x)
//ID3v2 size                 4 * %0xxxxxxx
```

---

Possible external sources:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataView

http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames

http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-structure

http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/08/reading-id3-tags-with-javascript.html

http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/8343485440/reading-mp3-id3-tags-in-javascript

https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader

I'm using the PHP getid3 lib at the moment...

http://getid3.sourceforge.net/

http://getid3.sourceforge.net/source2/module.tag.id3v2.phps

Comment: Could this help? https://github.com/antimatter15/js-id3v2

Comment: i'm searching for native functions... antimatter uses alot of polyfills... wich makes it very slow and unstable.it works great on many browsers ... but i just need it for chrome. i want only use the latest js 1.7+ for the important functions like ajax filereader dataview.... antimatter's code is good for one file... but if you need to handle multiple files this wouldn't be a good idea.

Comment: plus using chrome you can use persistent storage and so manipulate big files. wich, with more knowledge, would allow you also to write those tags to file. think also of the mp4 format.

Comment: I've used this with much success in Node.js, maybe you could run it through browserify? https://github.com/leetreveil/musicmetadata Since it expects a readable stream, you'd have to find a way to pack the data into a ReadableStream.  You could fetch the mp3 with XHR and set the responseType to 'arraybuffer' to work with the raw bytes.

Comment: the good thing on this is that it can run on the client side... why use node on your server to do the math if the client could do that ????

Comment: Anyway ... no proper solution found ... code should need to work only on chrome & safari... webkit browsers... that means.. 70-80% less code. if someone just hints me on how to parse properly the first string i would be able to write the rest and share it...antimatter15's code is great but most functions are nativ e now. base64= atob() & btoa(), dataview...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the code I found here: http://www.ulduzsoft.com/2012/07/parsing-id3v2-tags-in-the-mp3-files/, I translated it into Javascript here: http://jsfiddle.net/eb7rrbw4/

Here is the code as I wrote it there:

```
DataView.prototype.getChar=function(start) {
    return String.fromCharCode(this.getUint8(start));
};
DataView.prototype.getString=function(start,length) {
    for(var i=0,v='';i<length;++i) {
        v+=this.getChar(start+i);
    }
    return v;
};
DataView.prototype.getInt=function(start) {
    return (this.getUint8(start) << 21) | (this.getUint8(start+1) << 14) | (this.getUint8(start+2) << 7) | this.getUint8(start+3);
};

function readID3(){
    var a=new DataView(this.result);
    // Parse it quickly
    if ( a.getString(0,3)!="ID3" )
    {
        return false;
    }

    // True if the tag is pre-V3 tag (shorter headers)
    var TagVersion = a.getUint8(3);

    // Check the version
    if ( TagVersion < 0 || TagVersion > 4 )
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Get the ID3 tag size and flags; see 3.1
    var tagsize = a.getInt(6)+10;
        //(a.getUint8(9) & 0xFF) | ((a.getUint8(8) & 0xFF) << 7 ) | ((a.getUint8(7) & 0xFF) << 14 ) | ((a.getUint8(6) & 0xFF) << 21 ) + 10;
    var uses_synch = (a.getUint8(5) & 0x80) != 0 ? true : false;
    var has_extended_hdr = (a.getUint8(5) & 0x40) != 0 ? true : false;

    var headersize=0;         
    // Read the extended header length and skip it
    if ( has_extended_hdr )
    {
        var headersize = a.getInt(10);
            //(a.getUint8(10) << 21) | (a.getUint8(11) << 14) | (a.getUint8(12) << 7) | a.getUint8(13); 
    }

    // Read the whole tag
    var buffer=new DataView(a.buffer.slice(10+headersize,tagsize));

    // Prepare to parse the tag
    var length = buffer.byteLength;

    // Recreate the tag if desynchronization is used inside; we need to replace 0xFF 0x00 with 0xFF
    if ( uses_synch )
    {
        var newpos = 0;
        var newbuffer = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(tagsize));

        for ( var i = 0; i < tagsize; i++ )
        {
            if ( i < tagsize - 1 && (buffer.getUint8(i) & 0xFF) == 0xFF && buffer.getUint8(i+1) == 0 )
            {
                newbuffer.setUint8(newpos++,0xFF);
                i++;
                continue;
            }

            newbuffer.setUint8(newpos++,buffer.getUint8(i));                 
        }

        length = newpos;
        buffer = newbuffer;
    }

    // Set some params
    var pos = 0;
    var ID3FrameSize = TagVersion < 3 ? 6 : 10;
    var m_title;
    var m_artist;

    // Parse the tags
    while ( true )
    {
        var rembytes = length - pos;

        // Do we have the frame header?
        if ( rembytes < ID3FrameSize )
            break;

        // Is there a frame?
        if ( buffer.getChar(pos) < 'A' || buffer.getChar(pos) > 'Z' )
            break;

        // Frame name is 3 chars in pre-ID3v3 and 4 chars after
        var framename;
        var framesize;

        if ( TagVersion < 3 )
        {
            framename = buffer.getString(pos,3);
            framesize = ((buffer.getUint8(pos+5) & 0xFF) << 8 ) | ((buffer.getUint8(pos+4) & 0xFF) << 16 ) | ((buffer.getUint8(pos+3) & 0xFF) << 24 );
        }
        else
        {
            framename = buffer.getString(pos,4);
            framesize = buffer.getInt(pos+4);
                //(buffer.getUint8(pos+7) & 0xFF) | ((buffer.getUint8(pos+6) & 0xFF) << 8 ) | ((buffer.getUint8(pos+5) & 0xFF) << 16 ) | ((buffer.getUint8(pos+4) & 0xFF) << 24 );
        }

        if ( pos + framesize > length )
            break;

        if ( framename== "TPE1"  || framename== "TPE2"  || framename== "TPE3"  || framename== "TPE" )
        {
            if ( m_artist == null )
                m_artist = parseTextField( buffer, pos + ID3FrameSize, framesize );
        }

        if ( framename== "TIT2" || framename== "TIT" )
        {
            if ( m_title == null )
                m_title = parseTextField( buffer, pos + ID3FrameSize, framesize );
        }

        pos += framesize + ID3FrameSize;
        continue;
    }
    console.log(m_title,m_artist);
    return m_title != null || m_artist != null;
}

function parseTextField( buffer, pos, size )
{
    if ( size < 2 )
        return null;

    var charcode = buffer.getUint8(pos); 

    //TODO string decoding         
    /*if ( charcode == 0 )
        charset = Charset.forName( "ISO-8859-1" );
    else if ( charcode == 3 )
        charset = Charset.forName( "UTF-8" );
    else
        charset = Charset.forName( "UTF-16" );

    return charset.decode( ByteBuffer.wrap( buffer, pos + 1, size - 1) ).toString();*/
    return buffer.getString(pos+1,size-1);
}
```

You should see the title and author in the console log. Look at the parse text function, though, where the encoding determines the way to read the string. (search for TODO). Also I have not tested it with extended headers or uses_synch true or tag version 3.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36346510/2450730  i hope we can improve this minimal function further

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [id3 parser on github](https://github.com/43081j/id3).

[Here's your updated fiddle that logs the tags object in the console](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/s492L/81/)

With the [id3.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/43081j/id3/master/id3.min.js) included, all you need to do in your code is this:

```
function readFile(){
   id3(this.files[0], function(err, tags) {
       console.log(tags);
   })
}
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].addEventListener('change',readFile,false);
```

And here is the `tags` object as created by `id3`:

```
{
  "title": "Stairway To Heaven",
  "album": "Stairway To Heaven",
  "artist": "Led Zeppelin",
  "year": "1999",
  "v1": {
    "title": "Stairway To Heaven",
    "artist": "Led Zeppelin",
    "album": "Stairway To Heaven",
    "year": "1999",
    "comment": "Classic Rock",
    "track": 13,
    "version": 1.1,
    "genre": "Other"
  },
  "v2": {
    "version": [3, 0],
    "title": "Stairway To Heaven",
    "album": "Stairway To Heaven",
    "comments": "Classic Rock",
    "publisher": "Virgin Records"
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36346510/2450730  i hope we can improve this minimal function further

Answer (score 1):

**Partially Correct Answer** (it properly reads utf8 formatted id3v2.4.0 including cover)

> The things i asked in my question probably work now.

I wanted a very crude minimal function set to handle only id3v2.4.0 & and also parse the attached image.

With the help of @Siderite Zackwehdex, which answer is marked as correct, i understood the important part of the code that was missing.

As i had some time to play with it i made various modifications to the code.

First of all sorry for the compressed script but i have a better overview of the overall code. it's easier for me. if you have some questions about the code just ask.

Anyway, i removed the `uses_synch` ... it's really hard to find a file that uses synch. Same for the `has_extended_hdr`.I also remove the support for id3v2.0.0 to id3v2.2.0. I added a version check, that one works with all id3v2 subversions.

The main function output contains an array with all the tags, inside you can also find the id3v2 Version.Last, but i guess usefull to expand, i added a custom FRAME object that contains custom functions for FRAMES other than textFrames. The now only function inside converts the image/cover/APIC to a easy to use base64 string. Doing so the array can be stored as a JSON string.

While for some of you the compatibility is important the above mentioned exended header or sync are actually the smallest problem.

**PROBLEMS**

The encoding needs to be UTF-8 else you get strange text paddings and
 some images are parsed only partially. basically broken.

I want to avoid the use of external library or even a really big function just for that ... there needs to be some smart simple solution to handle properly the encoding.
ISO-8859-1,UTF-8,UTF-16 .. big endian... whatever... #00 vs #00 00 ..

If that is done the support can be improved exponentially.

I hope that some of you have a solution for that.

**CODE**

```
DataView.prototype.str=function(a,b,c,d){//start,length,placeholder,placeholder
 b=b||1;c=0;d='';for(;c<b;)d+=String.fromCharCode(this.getUint8(a+c++));return d
}
DataView.prototype.int=function(a){//start
 return (this.getUint8(a)<<21)|(this.getUint8(a+1)<<14)|
 (this.getUint8(a+2)<<7)|this.getUint8(a+3)
}
var frID3={
 'APIC':function(x,y,z,q){
  var b=0,c=['',0,''],d=1,e,b64;
  while(b<3)e=x.getUint8(y+z+d++),c[b]+=String.fromCharCode(e),
  e!=0||(b+=b==0?(c[1]=x.getUint8(y+z+d),2):1);
  b64='data:'+c[0]+';base64,'+
  btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,new Uint8Array(x.buffer.slice(y+z+++d,q))));
  return {mime:c[0],description:c[2],type:c[1],base64:b64}
 }
}
function readID3(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h){
 if(!(a=new DataView(this.result))||a.str(0,3)!='ID3')return;
 g={Version:'ID3v2.'+a.getUint8(3)+'.'+a.getUint8(4)};
 a=new DataView(a.buffer.slice(10+((a.getUint8(5)&0x40)!=0?a.int(10):0),a.int(6)+10));
 b=a.byteLength;c=0;d=10;
 while(true){
  f=a.str(c);e=a.int(c+4);
  if(b-c<d||(f<'A'||f>'Z')||c+e>b)break;
  g[h=a.str(c,4)]=frID3[h]?frID3[h](a,c,d,e):a.str(c+d,e);
  c+=e+d;
 }
 console.log(g);
}
```

**DEMO**

https://jsfiddle.net/2awq6pz7/