# Reading ID3 In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, filereader, id3

I'm trying to create a media player for Chromebooks using JavaScript. I need to read ID3 tags for MP3s, but I can't find a reliable ID3 reader.

[Eric Bidelman's solution using jDataView isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332384/read-id3-tags-from-mp3-using-javascript). It seems as though jDataView is meant for Node.js, while I'm looking for a browser-based solution.

All other resources I've found are sloppy/incomplete and don't work! Some don't even exist on Github anymore. ):

Is there a reliable resource to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader

Comment: See, I'm using the Chrome Filesystem API and I'm working with FileEntry objects and BLOB URLs. I just tried using this but it gave no feedback even. I tried to log the tags after passing a BLOB URL to that function but nothing happened.