# I want to get id3 tag with only javascript (NO NODE.JS)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making html audio player. If I input file with , It shows title, artist, album on id3 tag. But I can't find id3 tag reader on javascript.
I had found id3 reader on Node.js. But I spend 1 week, I can't understand Node.js.

So I want to get id3 tag with only Javascript. How can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332384/read-id3-tags-from-mp3-using-javascript) SO question.

Comment: @JeroenHeier This answer uses node.js module :\
I had watched that on Google