# Get audio metadata (e.g. artist, album, №), HTML

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I have an `<INPUT type="file" accept="audio/*"/>` element in my document. All the basic file data gets loaded, but can I somehow access the audio's (let's say .mp3 file's) extended metadata, such as artist name, album title, song number, perhaps even album art? Found pretty much nothing on the subject.

**EDIT:** The goal is to do this completely client-side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [read id3 tags from mp3 using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332384/read-id3-tags-from-mp3-using-javascript)

Comment: @ChrisG Managed to make jDataView work, forgot to mention that I am doing this fully client-side. Though it doesn't work always, as it appears that some of my files had UUU's at the end, instead of tag stuff. Thank you.